# How do I change image when a radio button is clicked in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

What is the simplest way to change the image of card when radio button or even button is clicked.

I wanted to display a list of cards (list of products) with every single card has 3 images with 3 radio buttons.

May this code explain more my purpose and I'm sure there is a better way than this:

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>
  .b1, .b2, .b3{
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}

.content {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

#y, #z, #b, #c{
display: none;
}

img {
   width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

button {
  outline: none;
}
</style>

<div class="container" style="float: left; margin-right: 50px" >
  <script>
    const x = () => {
  document.getElementById("x").style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById("y").style.display ='none'
  document.getElementById("z").style.display ='none'
}

const y = () => {
  document.getElementById("y").style.display ='block'
  document.getElementById("x").style.display ='none'
  document.getElementById("z").style.display ='none'
}

const z = () => {
  document.getElementById("z").style.display ='block'
  document.getElementById("x").style.display ='none'
  document.getElementById("y").style.display ='none'
}
  </script>
  <button class="b1" onClick="x()"></button>
  <button class="b2" onClick="y()"></button>
  <button class="b3" onClick="z()"></button>

<div class="content">
  <div id="x"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/22/53/heart-1776746_1280.jpg" /> </div>
  <div id="y"><img src="https://as.ftcdn.net/r/v1/pics/ea2e0032c156b2d3b52fa9a05fe30dedcb0c47e3/landing/images_photos.jpg" /> </div>
  <div id="z"><img src="http://indeksonline.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/photo-1500644813727-ac2ce0ae31f8.jpg" /> </div>
</div>
  </div>

<div class="container" style="float: left; margin-right: 50px">
  <script>
    const a = () => {
  document.getElementById("a").style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById("b").style.display ='none'
  document.getElementById("c").style.display ='none'
}

const b = () => {
  document.getElementById("b").style.display ='block'
  document.getElementById("a").style.display ='none'
  document.getElementById("c").style.display ='none'
}

const c = () => {
  document.getElementById("c").style.display ='block'
  document.getElementById("a").style.display ='none'
  document.getElementById("b").style.display ='none'
}
  </script>
  <button class="b1" onClick="a()"></button>
  <button class="b2" onClick="b()"></button>
  <button class="b3" onClick="c()"></button>

<div class="content">
  <div id="a"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/22/53/heart-1776746_1280.jpg" /> </div>
  <div id="b"><img src="https://as.ftcdn.net/r/v1/pics/ea2e0032c156b2d3b52fa9a05fe30dedcb0c47e3/landing/images_photos.jpg" /> </div>
  <div id="c"><img src="http://indeksonline.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/photo-1500644813727-ac2ce0ae31f8.jpg" /> </div>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm going to render dozen of products and I don't think this is a good way.

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: this doesnt look like React

Comment: if you have dozens of products then put them in an array and .map through them with each of them rendering it's own 3 buttons

Comment: Yes it's just HTML and JS and I want to do something like that with React

Comment: I've already done this: `export const products = [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: "Ray Ban",
        defaultImage: "images/product-1/1.jpg",
        secondImage: "images/product-1/2.jpg",
        thirdImage: "images/product-1/3.jpg",
        price: "90.99",
        description: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    ]`

Comment: Hi Someone Special thank you for your attention, do you think it's OK to render them with this method?